# npgsql returns table schema without primary key

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying to find a universal way of getting the column with the primary key inside a given table. I've tested the following code out

```cs
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);
var schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
```

This code works perfectly fine and all is good, I can find the column with the primary key easily from it for any SQL Server database, but when I try to use the `Npgsql` library on a PostgreSQL database, it labels all the columns (whether a column is the primary key or not) inside a given table as false.

Has anybody faced this issue before?

PS: I know that there are ways to get what I want using a query hack (`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` I mean), but I don't want to walk that road.

## Updated

Postgres Version: 14.5, NpgSQL: 6.0.6

## Example code

```sql
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    user_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

Whether I'm using a primary, or an identity it's still giving me false, on the other hand, in the below table the `isKey` column is marked true, but I'm in need of the `isIdentity` column to be marked true, any potential fixes?

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information: 1) Postgres version? 2) npgsql version? Add to question as update.

Comment: Would also be helpful to have an example table schema and the results you see returned.

Comment: Per [GetSchemaTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetSchemaTable) you should be looking for `IsKey`. `IsIdentity` marks an `Identity` column which appeared in Postgres 10+ and does not show up in `npgsql` per [Schema](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.Schema.NpgsqlDbColumn.html?q=GetSchemaTable).

Comment: Might also look at `IsAutoIncrement` as Postgres has more then one way to create auto-incrementing column.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver can you give more info about this?

Comment: [Create Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). The issue is `npgsql` AFAIK does not support `IsIdentity` so having an `identity` column will probably not change the outcome. At any rate you where looking for the PK and `IsKey` will show that.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver This is the solution to the problem, thank you!

Comment: FYI support is being added for IsIdentity in Npgsql, but to reflect whether a column is a PG identity column (which is again distinct from being a key), see https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/4688.